# Refatorar código SonarQube

Tags: c#, estilo-de-codificação, sonarqube

O que eu poderia fazer para melhorar esse código? O SonarQube indica que devo refatorar esse código, mas não apresenta nenhuma sugestão:

[image: SonarQube indicando problemas de Cognitive Complexity]

```
var dados = Set.Where(s => s.Id > 0);

    if (filtro.IdSolicitacao > 0)
    {
       dados = dados.Where(d => d.Id == filtro.IdSolicitacao);
    }
    else
    {
      if (filtro.IdFornecedor != 0)
        dados = dados.Where(d => d.IdPessoa == filtro.IdFornecedor);
      if (filtro.IdUsuarioSolicitacao != 0)
        dados = dados.Where(d => d.IdUsuarioSolicitacao == filtro.IdUsuarioSolicitacao);
      if (filtro.IdUsuarioAutorizacao != 0)
        dados = dados.Where(d => d.IdUsuarioAutorizacao == filtro.IdUsuarioAutorizacao);
      if (filtro.DataInicioSolicitacao != null)
        dados = dados.Where(d => d.DataSolicitacao >= filtro.DataInicioSolicitacao);
      if (filtro.DataFinalSolicitacao != null)
        dados = dados.Where(d => d.DataSolicitacao <= filtro.DataFinalSolicitacao);
      if (filtro.DataInicioAutorizacao != null)
        dados = dados.Where(d => d.DataAutorizacao >= filtro.DataInicioAutorizacao);
      if (filtro.DataFinalAutorizacao != null)
        dados = dados.Where(d => d.DataAutorizacao <= filtro.DataFinalAutorizacao);
      if (filtro.DataInicioVctoSolicitacao != null)
        dados = dados.Where(d => d.DataPagamentoAntecipacao >= filtro.DataInicioVctoSolicitacao);
      if (filtro.DataFinalVctoSolicitacao != null)
        dados = dados.Where(d => d.DataPagamentoAntecipacao <= filtro.DataFinalVctoSolicitacao);
      if (filtro.SituacaoSolicitacao != null)
      {
          var situacao = (SituacaoAntecipacaoFundoFinanceiro)filtro.SituacaoSolicitacao;
          dados = dados.Where(d => d.SituacaoSolicitacao == situacao);
      }
   }
```

Comment: Talvez colocando tudo num só comando LINQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isto foi respondido em: [SonarLint, complexidade do método "equals()"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/321911/101). Porque a questão é diminuir o número de `if`s , porém a complexidade cognitiva continuará, trágico se ele considerar que não. Então a forma de silenciá-lo será separar em vários método o que pode prejudicar o código em performance e até mesmo legibilidade.

Note que se você mudar tudo em um LINQ só realmente pode dar ganhos, até performance, mas depende de contexto. E pode até dar outro resultado em alguns casos. Para afirmar isto teríamos que saber que LINQ é este. Dependo dele tem que fazer de uma forma muito diferente disto. Sem contexto uma resposta pode causar mais estrago que solução, e a pessoa que não entende a motivação nem perceber. Pra mim o código todo precisa ser refatorado, mas só com isso não podemos ajudar.

Porém o que é mais importante é que isto não reduz a complexidade de fato, o que faz questionar a qualidade destes softwares. Ele pode ser bem usado se você entender tudo o que ele propõe, então ele serve só para indicar algo que você não percebeu que poderia fazer. Como ele tem regras questionáveis e não as explicam, ele pode causar mais mal do que bem. Pode começar piorar o código para cumprir o que ele manda.

Por isso que eu digo sempre que é preciso entender os fundamentos para não depende de terceiros mandando em você e nem poder questionar.